# Why do I get object not found with this simple ggplot plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a very simple dataset and I'm trying to make a very simple graph, but I get an object not found error and I can't determine why. Here's the output of head(techissues)

```
Event.Start.Date Were.you.able.to.see..hear.and.follow.the.presentation...
1        2011-09-29                                                       Yes
11       2011-09-19                                                       Yes
17       2011-09-19                                                       Yes
20       2011-08-30                                                        No
26       2011-09-29                                                       Yes
27       2011-09-29                                                       Yes
```

Here's the plot code:
`qplot(factor(techissues$Event.Start.Date), fill=as.character(techissues$Were.you.able.to.see..hear.and.follow.the.presentation...))`

I'm expecting a bar graph with the date strings along the x and a stacked bar showing the number of Yes and No for each date. I can make exactly this type plot on other datasets, and I don't understand how this one is different.

The error is `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'techissues' not found`

`summary(techissues)`

```
Event.Start.Date   Were.you.able.to.see..hear.and.follow.the.presentation...
Length:188         Length:188                                               
Class :character   Class :character                                         
Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

That's it. What's going on here?

Comment: When I posted this question, I noticed that the syntax highlighting colored `.and.` differently in the summary output. I changed the column name from that long string to `see.and.hear` and it works, so I don't know what happened. BTW, the long awkward column names weren't of my doing, I'm just working with what I was given. This has now motivated me to rename the columns as part of the *extensive* data cleanup I already have to do!

Answer (score 4):

`ggplot` and `qplot` expect that you supply a `data.frame` with the `data=` argument, and specify the aesthetic mapping within this frame, i.e. you should typically never use `$`:

```
qplot(carb, optden, data=Formaldehyde)
```

not

```
qplot(Formaldehyde$carb, Formaldehyde$optden)
```

though it may seem to work in some simple situations, it is mostly an undesired feature.

Comment: Thanks, baptiste. This doesn't answer my question about why it works in some cases and fails in others, but points for the advice.

Comment: My guess is that ggplot2 expects a different meaning for the special pattern `..xxx..`, as illustrated in the following `d = data.frame(x=1:10, y = 1:10, z.weird..name.. = 1:10); qplot(d$x, d$z.weird..name..)`. This pattern is used to refer to variables returned by ggplot2 stats functions, such as `..counts..`, etc. My advice would be to use more standard names.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the names as given, but as I note above, I'm already renaming columns as part of my cleanup and normalization, and leaving the $ out of the aes routes around the problem, too. For some reason, I thought you had to attach the data frame to do that.